# implementar Interface IXmlSerializable em uma classe

Tags: c#, .net, xml, interface

Tenho uma classe e preciso implementar a serialização e deserialização de dados em um estrutura XML usando `IXmlSerializable`, para isso na minha classe tenho que implementar os métodos, `GetSchema()`, `ReadXml(XmlReader)`, `WriteXml(XmlWriter)`, da Interface `IXmlSerializable`, alguém sabia me dizer como ficaria a implementação desses métodos com base na minha classe?

```
namespace XmlSerializationSample
{
    public class Order : IXmlSerializable
    {
        #region Local Variables

        private List<OrderDetails> _items = new List<OrderDetails>();

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Identificador do pedido.
        /// </summary>
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cliente associado.
        /// </summary>
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data do pedido.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Itens do pedido.
        /// </summary>
        public List<OrderDetails> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {

        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {

        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa realmente implementar os metodos ou apenas serializar as instâncias da classe?

Comment: serealizar as instâncias da classe.

Comment: ja ja te mando uma resposta, você precisa considerar cultura no xml?

Comment: opa, bacana. cultura no xml, não entendi !

Comment: A serialização é o ato de representar um objeto (deveras integralmente) em um formato serial, mas, muitas vezes se usa um XML para outras tarefas (enviar para um Webservice, etc) e nesses casos, é necessário que o XML reflita uma cultura específica, que vai contra o conceito de representar o objeto fielmente no formato de serialização escolhido (XML), ai está um problema.

Comment: ha entendi, precisa sim!

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta e ve se te atende

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, primeiro temos que ter cuidado com o conceito de Serializar, afinal, XML é usado para muita coisa hoje em dia e as pessoas tendem a chamar de serializar qualquer ação que gere um XML, conceitualmente isto está meio errado.

Segundo a WikiPedia:

> "...serialization is the process of translating data structures or
>   object state into a format that can be stored"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Em tradução livre:

> "Serialização é o proceso de traduzir (ou transformar) o estado
>   (geralmente em memória) de estruturas de dados ou objetos em um
>   formato que possa ser armazenado."

Ou seja, você pode pegar um objeto e gerar um Array de Bytes para mandar pela rede, pode gerar array de bytes para guardar em um arquivo no disco, enviar parametros de um processo pela rede para executar em outro servidor ou simplesmente gerar um XML para guardar no disco ou enviar para um Webservice.

O MSDN possui outros exemplos das necessidades da serialização, dê uma olhada depois ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)), a questão importante aqui é que a serialização deveria ser um método de representar **uma cópia do objeto**.

Ai começa o problema em usar as classes de serialização do .net para outras coisas, também tem o problema de que muitas vezes os projetistas de sistemas falham em deixar claros alguns conceitos no lugar para onde você manda o objeto serializado (geralmente um subsistema que você tem que se comunicar mas, que não projetou).

Já vi casos em que o subsistema variava a cultura das datas de forma diferente em locais diferentes.

Vamos a um código de exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace serialTest
{
    [XmlRoot("Casa")]
    public class Casa
    {
        int? id;
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
        public int? ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        string cor;
        [XmlElement("cor")]
        public string Cor
        {
          get { return cor; }
          set { cor = value; }
        }

        //mesmo atributo, duas propriedades.
        DateTime dataConstrucaoPadrao;
        [XmlElement("dataConstrucaoPadrao")]
        public DateTime DataConstrucaoPadrao
        {
            get { return dataConstrucaoPadrao; }
            set { dataConstrucaoPadrao = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("dataConstrucaoComCultura")]
        public string DataConstrucaoComCultura
        {
            get { return dataConstrucaoPadrao.ToString(); }
            set { dataConstrucaoPadrao = Convert.ToDateTime(value); }
        }
        //fim do teste de cultura

        [XmlElement("Sala")]
        public Sala sala;
    }
}
```

Agora uma classe menor para um elemento filho no XML da Casa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace serialTest
{
    [XmlRoot("Sala")]
    public class Sala
    {
        int? id;
        [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
        public int? ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        int quantJanelas;
        [XmlElement("QuantJanelas")]
        public int QuantJanelas
        {
            get { return quantJanelas; }
            set { quantJanelas = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Meu método Main da aplicação Console imprime na tela o XML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using serialTest;

namespace ConsoleTestSerial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Casa c;

            c = new Casa();

            c.Cor = "Vermelho";
            c.ID = 1;

            c.DataConstrucaoPadrao = DateTime.Now;

            c.sala = new Sala();
            c.sala.QuantJanelas = 2;
            c.sala.ID = 1;

            string resultSerial = UtilSerial.Serialize<Casa>(c);

            Console.WriteLine( resultSerial);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

E o XML gerado:

```
<Casa>
  <Sala>
    <QuantJanelas>2</QuantJanelas>
  </Sala>
  <cor>Vermelho</cor>
  <dataConstrucaoPadrao>2016-11-03T14:25:17.5677191-03:00</dataConstrucaoPadrao>
  <dataConstrucaoComCultura>03/11/2016 14:25:17</dataConstrucaoComCultura>
</Casa>
```

Falta o código que gera o XML, mas, vou deixar isso pro final porque basicamente não importa, já que uso um metodo genérico e estatico para serializar ou deserializar, o problema mesmo está forma como escrevi as classes e vamos focar nisso.

Começando com os problemas:

**1. As classes de serialização foram feitas para serializar (gerar uma cópia) e tentam garantir que você nao se preocupe com o resto, logo, elas usam cultura invariante, se precisar variar a cultura, faça você mesmo.**

Não adianta setar a cultura da aplicação e da thread se o código da classe que será serializada não tiver uma adaptação.

Veja por exemplo o atributo DateTime dataConstrucaoPadrao da Classe Casa, altere seu código para usar propriedades, você está usando os atributos de forma pública, além de ser um anti-padrão, você terá problemas para serializar porque vai precisar alterar o retorno sem alterar o tipo de dados. Aplique uma refatoração no seu código e leve isso para frente em outros projetos.

Repare eu eu gero duas interpretações do atributo no XML, usando proprieades, uma reflete a cultura e a outra não, no entanto, são o mesmo atributo.

Isso é possivel porque a cultura padrão é aplicada quando serializo um datetime, mas, eu crio uma propriedade do tipo string que retornar o .ToString da data, então será serializado o resultado do ToString e não a data, ai o ToString usa a cultura da Thread antes de serializar, no meu caso, pt-br.

**Então, se precisar gerar o XML em cultura específica, use um atributo do tipo String e retorne o ToString do atributo.**

Eu seto essa cultura na frente, espere um pouco.

**2. Objetos muitas vezes tem atributos que você não quer enviar no XML se está gerando ele para ir pra outro sistema.**

Perceba que o Atributo ID das minhas classes precisa existir para identificar o objeto no meu sistema (e provavelmente no banco de dados) mas, não é um atributo util no meu XML (eu nem coloco ele lá).

bom, ai é fácil, basta usar [XmlIgnoreAttribute] e ta tudo beleza, só que não.

Primeiro, existe um problema conceitual, o meu XML não é mais uma cópia do objeto que existia em memória, então, não posso mais garantir que consigo reproduzir o estado da aplicação antes de gerar o XML, se precisar inverter o processo, vai ter problemas em saber quem é quem no banco de dados ou em outros locais. Depois, o atributo ID vai precisar ser nulo na volta, logo, precisa ser anulável.

Geralmente, nessas situações existe algum campo que faz parte da regra de negócio que talvez possa ser usado como chave primária (CPF, RG, etc).

Mas, você está usando a serialização fora da definição de serialização.

Então porque eu devo usar essas classes? Bom, você que sabe se deve ou não usar.

É muito facil botar um atributo na classe e gerar um XML com o método genérico, logo, a facilidade as vezes é melhor do que a perfeição. Um aplicativo simples, que vai rodar apenas para uma tabela ou rotina pequena, pode ser feito em alguns minutos no lugar de dias.

O problema geralmente é a manutenção.

E por fim, a classe genérica para serializar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace serialTest
{
    public class UtilSerial
    {
        public static string Serialize<T>(T dataToSerialize)
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo n = new CultureInfo("pt-br");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = n;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = n;

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

                var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");

                var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });

                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, dataToSerialize, ns);

                return stringwriter.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText)
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo n = new CultureInfo("pt-br");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = n;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = n;

                var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui muitos fatores já ficam claros quando olhamos o código, acho que apenas a questão da cultura vale um adendo.

Estes métodos vão gerar representações de atributos com culturas diferentes. Todos os atributos / propriedades que forem definidos na classe de forma a ter um retorno de um tipo padrão (int, string, datetime, etc) vão ser representados com cultura invariante, os que tiverem como retorno algum método que utiliza cultura para gerar a saída (geralmente ToString), terão sua saída na cultura que está sendo configurada na thread desses métodos, neste caso, pt-br.

O mesmo vale para a entrada.

Conceitos básicos:

- [XmlRoot("Sala")] - Raiz do XML, use na definição da classe.
- [XmlElement("cor")] - No do XML, use nos nós do XML.

Para atributos que forem Listas Genéricas de Objetos:

- [XmlArray("Salas")] - Gera o atributo raiz da lista
- [XmlArrayItem("Sala")] - gera cada item da lista

Neste caso, se nossa classe Casa tivesse uma lista de Salas:

```
private List<Sala> salas;
[XmlArray("Salas")]
[XmlArrayItem("Sala")]
public List<Sala> Salas
{
       get { return salas; }
       set { salas = value; }
}
```

Bom, pra finalizar, usando esta estrutura, todas as vezes que precisar gerar um XML de uma classe basta definir os atributos e chamar os metódos da classe UtilSerial e ja ta pronto.

[Uma boa conversa sobre Serialização em C++ do Marshall Cline.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405013606/http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Answer (score 1):

Na maioria dos casos não é necessário implementar `IXmlSerializable`.

Instâncias de classes relativamente simples como a sua podem ser serializadas diretamente por `XMLSerializer` sem problemas.

Caso o xml resultante da serialização padrão não atenda a sua necessidade, [certos atributos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx) podem ser aplicados nos elementos da sua classe para refinar o processo de serialização.

Comment: entendi, está classe é bem simples, neste caso é apenas um estudo para que eu possa serializar uma entidade inteira, de comlexidade bem maior, por isso queria entender como serealizar os atributos da minha classe, no método.

Comment: Será que ficaria algo do tipo?



    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
           this.OrderId = reader.GetAttribute("OrderId ")
    }

Comment: @fernandotso Leia a documentação do IxmlSerializable no [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx). Existem 2 raras situações onde é necessário implementar esta interface. Se de fato ainda for necessário implementá-la, use os parâmetros reader/writer dos métodos para ler/escrever o xml, respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

segue um exemplo que usei para
Serializar e Deserializar um XML usando C#

```
    [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot("Pessoa"), XmlType("Pessoa")]
        public class Pessoa
        {
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Data")]
            public string Data { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("DadosPessoais")]
            public DadosPessoais DadosPessoais { get; set; }
        }

        public class DadosPessoais
        {
            [XmlElement("Nome")]
            public string Nome { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("CPF")]
            public string Cpf { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Endereco")]
            public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
        }

        public class Endereco
        {
            [XmlElement("Bairro")]
            public string Bairro { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Cidade")]
            public string Cidade { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Estado")]
            public string Estado { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Cep")]
            public string Cep { get; set; }
        }


    public class XmlWorkReader
        {
            private string _fullpath;

            public XmlWorkReader(string _fullpath)
            {
                this._fullpath = _fullpath;
            }

            public void ConvertXMltoClass<TXml>()
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(_fullpath))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TXml));
                    TXml txml = (TXml)xs.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
        }




 public class XmlWorkWriter
    {
        private XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer;
        private string _path;
        private string _filename;
        private string _fullpath;

        public XmlWorkWriter(string _path, string _filename)
        {
            this._path = _path;
            this._filename = _filename;
            _fullpath = Path.Combine(_path, _filename + ".xml");
        }


        public void XmlWrite<Txml>(Txml xml)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_fullpath))
                {
                    _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Txml));
                    _xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, xml);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }
```

exemplo no github
https://github.com/EduardoSampaio/Projeto-Serializando-Deserializando-XML